# java - Joining 2 Spark dataframes, getting result as list

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to join 2 dataframes, but I would like to have the result as a list of rows of the right dataframe (`dDf` in the example below) in a column of the left dataframe (`cDf` in the example).

I made it work with one column, but having **issues adding more columns**.

```
    Seq<String> joinColumns = new Set2<>("c1", "c2").toSeq();
    Dataset<Row> allDf = cDf.join(dDf, joinColumns, "inner");
    allDf.printSchema();
    allDf.show();

    Dataset<Row> aggDf = allDf
            .groupBy(cDf.col("c1"), cDf.col("c2"))
            .agg(collect_list(col("c50")));
    aggDf.show();
```

Output:

```
+--------+-------+---------------------------+
|c1      |c2     |collect_list(c50)          |
+--------+-------+---------------------------+
|    3744|1160242|         [6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]|
|    3739|1150097|                        [1]|
|    3780|1159902|            [5, 4, 3, 2, 1]|
|     132|1200743|               [4, 3, 2, 1]|
|    3778|1183204|                        [1]|
|    3766|1132709|                        [1]|
|    3835|1146169|                        [1]|
+--------+-------+---------------------------+
```

Also, is there a way to do something like:

```
    Dataset<Row> aggDf = allDf
            .groupBy(cDf.col("*"))
            .agg(collect_list(col("c50")));
```

Comment: with scala  you can do `allDf.groupBy(cDf.schema.map(_.name).map(c => col(c).as(c) ): _*)`  , sorry i don't know the java syntaxe

Answer (score 1):

For the second part of the question, you can do:

```
    String[] fields = cDf.columns();
    Column[] columns = new Column[fields.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < fields.length; i++) {
        columns[i] = cDf.col(fields[i]);
    }
    Dataset<Row> sDf = allDf.groupBy(columns).agg(...);
```

Answer (score 0):

**You can use `collect_list` to collect a `struct` that contains all columns of dataframe `dDf`. You can retrieve columns of `dDf` using `.columns()` method**

So your code becomes:

```java
import org.apache.spark.sql.Column;
import org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset;
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row;
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions;
import scala.collection.Seq;
import scala.collection.immutable.Set.Set2;
import java.util.Arrays;
import static org.apache.spark.sql.functions.collect_list;
import static org.apache.spark.sql.functions.struct;

...

Seq<String> joinColumns = new Set2<>("c1", "c2").toSeq();
Dataset<Row> allDf = cDf.join(dDf, joinColumns, "inner");

Column[] dDfColumns = Arrays.stream(dDf.columns())
  .filter(n -> !joinColumns.contains(n)) // remove this line if you want to keep join columns
  .map(functions::col)
  .toArray(Column[]::new);

Column[] cDfColumns = Arrays.stream(cDf.columns())
  .map(functions::col)
  .toArray(Columns[]::new);

Dataset<Row> aggDf = allDf
  .groupBy(cDfColumns)
  .agg(collect_list(struct(dDfColumns)));

aggDf.show();
```